# Would or would have

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

Which sentence is correct.

*I always thought it would be so much fun to travel around the country in 90s.

*I always thought it would have been so much fun to travel around the country in 90s.

Comment: Is it still a possibility or not?

Comment: I think rather not, the 90s overed.

Comment: Then I suggest you use the perfect. It's suitable for things that have been completed. :)

Comment: So is there a possibility to use "I always thought it would be so much fun to travel around the country in 90s?

Comment: If it hasn't yet happened, or if it did and experienced proved the thought wrong, you could say that. For example, if you're travelling around the country during the '90s and not enjoying it at all, you could say, "I always thought it would be fun, but... this is a disappointment."

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with "I always thought". The "thought" could have been at any time up to now.

So either could be OK depending on the specific time you mean in the larger context.

> I recalled making travel plans in 1989. I always thought (in this case time up to 1989) it **would be** so much fun to travel around the country in *the* 90s if I could find a good woman to travel with.

or

> Last week I was wondering why I never travel anywhere. I always thought (in this case time up to last week) it **would have been** so much fun to travel around the country in *the* 90s, but I was too poor to do that.